# "Box generator"-like software for laser cutting this shelf from MDF

Tags: wood, milling

I'm thinking of building this shelf out of 1/4" thick MDF:

[image]

Now knowing how slow I am in the most basic of woodworking, I want the job to be speedy & easy. So I decided laser cutting it & joining it with finger joints, would be an excellent way to go about it.

The problem is producing the vector file that will be fed to the laser cutter. The cuts, with it's finger joints, would be time consuming to be manually drawn in a vector graphics software, not to mention error prone.

So I need an automated way of generating these cuts to a file. Sort of like what a lot of these "box generators" do (except the shelves are tilted):

https://makerdesignlab.com/tutorials-tips/online-file-generators-for-laser-cutting/

Maybe there is a hack that would take boxes generated by these generators & modify/chuck-away certain parts to end up with the shelf in the picture.

Comment: What's the scale of the one you want to make, you weren't planning on loading it with books were you? If you're thinking of scaling it down to hold only small items you're probably fine (although I'd still be tempted to use HDF instead) but if you want a full-size one, and it's intended to take much weight, this . isn't really suited to MDF.

Comment: It looks to me like these are 90 degree angles at the joints other than the very bottom one, and all the 'shelves' should be identical except for the bottom one as well.  Of course the top one wouldn't need the holes for for finger joints but it would but up to you if that was a problem.   and I agree with Graphus, MDF especially 1/4" isn't very strong for a shelf like this of any size.

Comment: 1/4" MDF isn't suitable for any shelf outside of a dollhouse.

Comment: Also, I don't understand where the finger joints are supposed to be. Or why you'd want to use finger joints at all with this design.

Comment: I want a dirt-cheap shelving solution for my brushes, dowels, zip ties, etc that are all very vertical. With this in mind, I decided going full vertical is the way to go. First, I considered shelves with tall spacings, but, when I happened on this vertical-tilted design, I knew this was the right solution. The stuff to be put in here aren't typically that heavy, but I'm quite open to changing/adapting material/approach.

Comment: For the very light items you indicate this should work but thicker material, or plywood or HDF, would still be better. Rereading the body of the Q, this stood out for me *"The cuts, with it's finger joints, would be time consuming to be manually drawn in a vector graphics software, not to mention error prone."* Neither of those things are true, unless the program is very lacking. If you were for example to use an old version of Illustrator it's accurate to sub-sub-millimetre accuracy (+/-0.0001"), and since you can step & repeat items, once you've done one finger the rest take maybe 5 seconds!

Comment: @bowlturner, I was assuming non-square joints from the start (because that's what the photo shows) but the more I look at it the more I'm sure the photo has been squished. It makes much more sense, and would be far far easier to build of course, if this had 90° joints on all the shelves, with only the bottom one being angled (45° I presume).

Comment: @MikeBaranczak, with any unsupported span I'd sort of agree, but there are numerous hobby storage solutions that use laser-cut 1/4" MDF and for the weights each thing has to support it appears to work fine.

Comment: @Graphus: I benchmarked myself creating a small bracket with finger joints, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Av5oULPolDwX8ccfKiiBnsSe2Sj6lnse/view?usp=sharing. I used Inkscape, as technically speaking, a slice is all you need. I initially thought 3D CAD-ing is overdoing it. But, I've learn it's really helpful if you can pick up one cut & then make sure it fits with the right thickness, etc. Only when you're already good at drawing finger joints do you just casually gloss  over it.

Comment: I can't get that SVG to work so don't know what it shows. I'm not glossing over the difficulty here I don't think – for the piece with the tenons there are multiple methods but they all start with a rectangle of known size, stepped and repeated as needed. The full process I'm envisaging a pro could do in no time at all (<60 secs, one of my mates could do it in literally 20 seconds) but if it takes a regular person a full five minutes that doesn't seem like a long time. For the mating piece I presume you just draw the perimeter, then step and repeat a small rectangle for the slots/mortises?

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is producing the vector file that will be fed to the laser cutter. The cuts, with its finger joints, would be time consuming to be manually drawn in a vector graphics software, not to mention error prone.

Any half-decent CAD package would handle this easily: you'd only have to draw one or two of the diagonal pieces, along with their joinery, and then you could simply duplicate those for the other diagonal parts. With the diagonal parts arranged, you could draw in the vertical support and horizontal base, subtract the diagonal parts to cut joinery holes. Then lay all the parts out flat to create a vector file for your laser cutter.

That said, laser cut box/finger joints seem like a lot of trouble for this project. You've got a total of nine parts, seven of which are identical except for a bevel on the bottom diagonal. The horizontal base is also the same width as the diagonals. It's hard to tell whether the vertical support is the same width. Starting with a sheet of 1/4" material, you'd only need to rip a few strips, cut the strips to length, and then glue them together with perhaps some nails or staples to hold things in place. If you've got a table saw, or access to one, you'll be done before the laser cutter finishes cutting the parts.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I've got an approach of my own. I'll use a generator to have T-beams like these:

[image]

Then I can keep on connecting them in zigzag. It's reasonably not-so-hard that I may manually do this in a vector program, but I'd still rather go for a generator.

The back, which is the main support, I may use a thicker piece of wood (still have to decide). I'm thinking of cutting tilted grooves at the back, instead of finger joining it (an incentive to use thicker wood). So that will go to the table saw, where I can repeatedly cut dados at the fixed intervals. It's fine that the grooves go through the whole side-to-side. I'll just plug it.

Comment: The advantage of CAD vs. a 2D vector drawing program is that you can make sure that your parts fit together before you ever cut them.

Comment: If you moved the right angles a tiny bit to the outside, your dados could meet at the edge and you wouldn’t need to plug/fill anything.